# Add array as "range" of EmbeddedChart in Google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Brief:** I want to change the data in an Google sheets EmbeddedChart by using an array generated within the embedded Google script without pouring the data into cells first.

**Long:** I have an bound script that updates a preexisting spreadsheet. I modify the data in js and want to change an embedded chart to use the generated array of data without putting the data on the table. I technically do not care that it is an EmbeddedChart I just want to make a summary page with a graph without polluting the document with an extra sheet. Would prefer not to make an HTML page out of the sheet.

I have tried various options.

`.setDataTable()` is not a method of `EmbeddedChartBuilder`, unlike normal (HTML) Google Charts. I am assuming I am missing something simple, like some class that converts an array to a pseudo-Range instances akin to a DataTable or Excel's names, without touching the sheet.

Worst case scenario: I am not aware of a method to add a div with id attrib in Google sheets, is there one?

Ways tested:

- `sheet.getCharts()[0].modify().addRange([2,3,4,5]);` //Cannot convert Array to Range.
- `sheet.getCharts()[0].modify().addRange("{2,3,4,5}");` //Cannot find method addRange(string).
- (Desparate...) `sheet.getCharts()[0].modify().setDataTable();` //Cannot find function setDataTable in object EmbeddedChartBuilder.
- (Desparate...) `sheet.updateChart(chartFromCharts);` //Cannot find method updateChart(Chart).
- Magically convert array to a range object without saving on a sheet

  //Demo script.
  function populate() {
    var a=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var chart=sheet.getCharts()[0].modify();
    chart.setOption('title', "Changed in script...");
    cchart=chart.asColumnChart();
    dt=Charts.newDataTable().addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, "Categorical abscissa").addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "Numerical ordinate").addRow(["A",5]).addRow(["B",6]).build();

  //Try 1. Desparate just in case it accepts arrays.
    //chart.addRange(a);  //Cannot convert Array to Range.
    //cchart.addRange(a);  //Cannot convert Array to Range. 
    //Try 2. Desparate just in case it accepts DataTable
    //chart.addRange(dt); //Cannot find method addRange(DataTable). 
    //Try 3. Desparate hack...
    //new google.visualization.ColumnChart(getCharts()[0].getId()).draw(dt, options); //ReferenceError: "google" is not defined
    //Could I have accessed it anyway?
    //$(getCharts()[0].getId()).html("Hacked") //ReferenceError: "$" is not defined.
    //again...
    //document.getElementByID(getCharts()[0].getId()) //ReferenceError: "document" is not defined. 
    //Try 5.
    //sheet.updateChart(Charts.newColumnChart().build()); //Cannot find method updateChart(Chart).
    //Try 4. Missing method in documentation?!
    //chart.addDataTable(a); //Cannot find function addDataTable in object EmbeddedChartBuilder.

  //cchart.addDataTable(a); //Cannot find function addDataTable in object EmbeddedColumnChartBuilder.

  sheet.updateChart(chart.build());
  }

Comment: what have you tried so far? Could you clarify a little bit more on what you want to do?... check this document on how to ask questions in Stack Overflow http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: My aim is simply to make a chart in google sheets without having to make a new sheet with the data required and without making an HTML page or similar outside of the sheet —as that would defeat its purpose. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using Embedded Chart use normal [Charts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/) object and use .getAs(MimeType.PNG) to add the chart to the spreadsheet as an image.

*Edit:* I've tried this solution and because of google's bug when you get the spreadsheet as PDF the images inserted by script do not show. Google please fix this, it's been 3 years since it was reported and they're still "working on it"..